# Tail lights, brake lights, and plate lights out

Tags: saturn, tail-lights

I have a 2000 Saturn LS, and none of the back lights work, they all went out at once. I know nothing about cars and I don't want to go to a shop and pay out the butt for it

Comment: Saloon or estate / brake - check the cables in the rear have they been broken, have you checked the fuses? But as you say "all" then there is more than one fuse involved...

Comment: Check the fuses first, all the lights might be on one of them. If that's not it then it could be a significant amount of work which would require knowledge and tools.

Comment: When you say "none of the lights work", this to me would include the reverse, parking, blinkers, and brake lights ... is this accurate?

Comment: By none of the lights I mean, brakes, reverse, blinkers, park, tail light, and plate lights. No lights in my rear work